# Your typical riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I tick like a clock,
>
> But the hands are red and yellow for some reason.
>
> When I alarm, I wave my hands pretty fast,
>
> And when I notice when its midnight, both hands put down to 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the answer

> Semaphore flags?

Expansion

> Semaphore flags are red and yellow and are held in one’s hands.
> Waving the flags is the code for “Attention”, or alarm.
> Both flags down signifies the end of a word, like how midnight is the end of the day?
> Not sure what the ticking means, but everything else seems to fit well enough.

Comment: The ticking could just mean that rot13(gur cbfvgvbaf bs gur nezf sbe n pybpx naq n crefba hfvat frzncuber syntf ybbx fvzvyne)?